# delete items from list of list: pythonic way

Tags: python, list, loops

I've this kind of list of list (only two nested level):

`my_list = [['A'], ['B'], ['C','D','A','B'], ['E'], ['B', 'F', 'G'], ['H']]`

I've a list of items to delete in `my_list`:

`to_del = ['A','B']`

this is my idea of code to delete `to_del` elements from `my_list`:

```
for i in my_list:
    for d in to_del:
        if d in i:
            i.remove(d)
```

Output:
`[[], [], ['C', 'D'], ['E'], ['F', 'G'], ['H']]`

Here my questions:

- Can you suggest a more pythonic/elegant way to do the same
- Can you suggest a smart way to generalize the number of nested levels 
  e.g `my_list = [ ['A'], ['B'], ['C', ['D', 'E', ['F']], 'G'], ['H'] ]`
- The ideal method will have a boolean argument `empty_lists` to decide whether or not keep empty lists.

Comment: Do you want to keep the empty lists?

Comment: you've notice that. well, the ideal method has a boolean argument `empty_lists` to decide whether or not keep the empty lists

Comment: Welcome to [so]. We have edit history for those who are really interested in how the post evolved over time, so there is no need to put in "EDIT:". You should always integrate new information to form a single coherent post, instead of lazily tagging on information and making the post harder to read than necessary. And if you really need to draw attention to something, DON'T SHOUT, but use **bold**, or *italics*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With nested list comprehensions:

```
[[y for y in x if y not in to_del] for x in my_list]
```

With list comprehension and lambda filter:

```
[filter(lambda y: y not in to_del, x) for x in my_list]
```

An attempt for the general case of arbitrarily nested lists:

```
def f(e):
    if not isinstance(e,list):
        if e not in to_del:
            return e
    else:
        return filter(None,[f(y) for y in e])

to_del = ['A','B']
my_list= [['A'], ['B',['A','Z', ['C','Z','A']]], ['C','D','A','B'],['E'], ['B','F','G'], ['H']]

>>> f(my_list)
[[['Z', ['C', 'Z']]], ['C', 'D'], ['E'], ['F', 'G'], ['H']]
```

Comment: i like it. for particular case of two nested level i solved with: `list(filter(None, [[s for s in sublist if s not in to_del] for sublist in my_list]))`. a question: you shouldn't cast `f` with `list(f(my_list))` since it returns an iterator?

Comment: @Nicola Python 2 returns a list ... looks like it's time for me to switch to Python 3

Answer (score 8):

Try list comprehension:

```
my_list = [[x for x in sublist if x not in to_del] for sublist in my_list]
```

Output:

```
>>> my_list
[[], [], ['C', 'D'], ['E'], ['F', 'G'], ['H']]
```