# Filtering function for an arbitrary nested list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, lambda, functional-programming

I can't find out how to write this function as a lambda because of the double conditional:

```
def f(e):
    if not isinstance(e,list):
        if e >10:
            return e
    else:
        return filter(None,[f(y) for y in e])
my_list=[[1], [2,[3,12, [4,11,12]]], [5,6,13,14],[15]]

>>> f(my_list)
[[[12, [11, 12]]], [13, 14], [15]]
```

Also, what would be the *pythonic way* to write such a function that filters arbitrarily nested lists?

Comment: Do you want `None` to be returned in the case where `e` is not a `list` and `e <= 10`? Also, more serious than the double conditional is the recursive nature of your function. Just how do you expect to recurse when the function has no name to call?

Comment: "what would be the pythonic way to write such a function" -- not as a lambda?

Comment: @RoryDaulton no,that's why I had to filter it out

Comment: Then what is to be returned? A function always returns *something*--if no `return` statement is encountered then `None` is returned.

Comment: How about if you explain in words what you want the function to do?

Comment: In Python 3.5.2 your code does not return the value `[[[12, [11, 12]]], [13, 14], [15]]` when `f(my_list)` is executed-- I got the value `<filter at 0x2057edc7b70>`. Do you really get a list result, and which version of Python did you use?

Comment: I'm trying to solve [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41313232/2314737) I wrote [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41313450/2314737) for the general case but I think it can be improved.

Comment: Your going to end up with a pretty hard to read function. Must is be a lambda?

Comment: @RoryDaulton I can't reproduce your result, I get a list (using Python2.7)

Comment: @RoryDaulton I think you are using Python 3, where `filter()` returns a "filter" object, if you want to see the list, use `list(filter(...))` ([reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319025/filters-in-python3))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, there is nothing wrong with defining a filtering or mapping function as a regular function via `def` if it would be a benefit to readability - remember ["Readability counts" and "Sparse is better than dense"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id3). Just because there are inline `lambda` function in the language, does not mean you have to squeeze your logic into it.

Since you eventually want to build a generic solution for an arbitrary list depth, you can *recursively apply the filtering function* via [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) + [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) to remove the `None` values:

```
def filter_function(e):
    if isinstance(e, list):
        return filter(None, map(filter_function, e))
    elif e > 10:
        return e

my_list = list(filter_function(my_list))
```

Note that `list()` would be needed on Python 3.x, since [`filter()` does not return a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319025/filters-in-python3).

---

Demo:

```
>>> my_list = [[1], [2, [3, 12, [4, 11, 12]]], [5, 6, 13, 14], [15]]
>>> 
>>> def filter_function(e):
...     if isinstance(e, list):
...         return filter(None, map(filter_function, e))
...     elif e > 10:
...         return e
... 
>>> 
>>> print(list(filter_function(my_list)))
[[[12, [11, 12]]], [13, 14], [15]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is not a best practice, but you can create a lambda function: use parenthesis to group conditions:

```
f = lambda e: filter(None, [f(y) for y in e]) if isinstance(e, list) else (e if e > 10 else None)

my_list = [[1], [2, [3, 12, [4, 11, 12]]], [5, 6, 13, 14], [15]]

>>> f(my_list)
[[[12, [11, 12]]], [13, 14], [15]]
```

For python 3 users:

```
f = lambda e: list(filter(None, [f(y) for y in e])) if isinstance(e, list) else (e if e > 10 else None)
```